# Handle Images using webApi 2

Tags: asp.net, image, asp.net-web-api, handle

I am using webApi 2 for my application. i have gallery and i need a way to show my images. I've searched a lot and found some articles like these :

```
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/1120/aspnet-webapi-binary-contents-images
https://jamessdixon.wordpress.com/2013/10/01/handling-images-in-webapi/
```

but they seems they don't have a efficient way.

so I decide to ask  this question once again. how can I handle my images in web api 2 ?

what's the best approach?

Comment: Without a little more info on your use case, it's hard to know what the best way would be. Typically a formatter would be used http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters Then your client would make two requests, /api/Images to get all your images, then create the proper views for each image (HTML would be `<img src="/api/Images/{id}.jpg" />`). A route that accepts an extension is needed and a formatter to return the proper content type and binary data. Your controller could do all the binary streaming, but a formatter allows better flexibility.

Comment: @ManOVision  thank you very much .... so what's your opinion about using BSON ?!! or i should go for reponse write ?1

Comment: I have never used BSON. Our API has so many different clients that JSON is universal for our DTO's. For images, we always use the the response body for the pure binary stream. This way there is no custom parsing that each client has to do. We can rely completely on the HTTP specs by using the proper content-type, content-length, etc. This also allows for a range request so we can stream and do partial downloads with resume. I have no doubt BSON will catch on and we'll probably use it in the future, but for now it doesn't fit our use case.

Comment: @ManOVision thank you very very much ... type your comments as an answer so i can mark them as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a little more info on your use case, it's hard to know what the best way would be. Typically a [formatter](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters) would be used. Then your client would make two requests, /api/Images to get all your images, then create the proper views for each image (HTML would be ). A route that accepts an extension is needed and a formatter to return the proper content type and binary data. Your controller could do all the binary streaming, but a formatter allows better flexibility.

As for BSON, I have never used BSON. Our API has so many different clients that JSON is universal for our DTO's. For images, we always use the the response body for the pure binary stream. This way there is no custom parsing that each client has to do. We can rely completely on the HTTP specs by using the proper content-type, content-length, etc. This also allows for a range request so we can stream and do partial downloads with resume. I have no doubt BSON will catch on and we'll probably use it in the future, but for now it doesn't fit our use case.